# Angular 2 add new item from input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input

Im new to Angular2 and Im trying to add a new item to the list from input. But then click to submit me instead of text [object Object].

Here is my code:

app.component.html

```
<form (submit)="addItem(item)">
    <md-input-container>
      <input [(ngModel)]="name" mdInput placeholder="add" name="addNew">
    </md-input-container>
      <button type="submit" md-icon-button>
          <i class="material-icons">send</i>
    </button>
    </form>
```

app.component.ts

```
items = Players;
 name;

 addItem(name): void {
        this.items.push(new Player({
            name : name
        }));
    }
```

player.ts

```
export class Player {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    count: number;

    constructor(name){
        this.id;
        this.name = name;
        this.count = 0;
    }
```

all-players.ts

```
export let Players: Player[] = [
];
```

Thank you for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write a complete answer.

In your component (TS file) :

```
items = Players;
name;

addItem() { this.items.push(new Player({ name : this.name })); }
```

In your HTML :

```
<form (submit)="addItem()" novalidate>
    <md-input-container>
        <input [(ngModel)]="name" mdInput placeholder="add" name="addNew">
    </md-input-container>
    <button type="submit" md-icon-button>
        <i class="material-icons">send</i>
    </button>
</form>
```

My guess on that is that you submit your form 2 times.

Comment: Hmm you are right but after changing the type of button I still get [object Object]

Comment: In what ? The input or your player?

Comment: Anyway, use my code and your problems will go. The problem here is that your method addItem asks for a parameter, that you called name. But in your html, you send item ! Either you delete the parameter and do as I wrote, or you send the name instead of the item. In both cases, you won't have anymore problems.